# Indexing error when rendering colors on a grid in PyGame

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I am creating a grid that changes colors when an object overlaps with it.

The error I am receiving is :

> ```
> color = colorList[min(len(colorList)-1, hitGrid[row][column])]
> IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40"
> ```

I am wondering how to fix this error. I have tried to reverse row and column, which works but the rendering of the colors is incorrect. Could it be an issue with how the rgb values is set in NumPy or just a way I have written my code?

---

My code is as follows:

VARIABLES

```
MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GRIDX, GRIDY = 1, 10, 10, 100, 40
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((GRIDX * (WIDTH+MARGIN) + MARGIN, GRIDY * (HEIGHT+MARGIN) + 50), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

DRAW GRID TO SCREEN

```py
def drawGrid(screen, hitGrid, colorList):
    # Draw the grid to the screen
    for row in range(GRIDY):
        for column in range(GRIDX):
            rect = [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN, (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT]
            #print(rect)
            #color = [255,255,255]
  
            color = colorList[min(len(colorList)-1, hitGrid[row][column])]

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
```

COLOR LIST

```py
rgbValues = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    rgbValues.append([255, 255, 255])

for j in range(1, 100):
    list_value = rgbValues[j]
    list_value[1] = round(list_value[1] - (j * 2.58))
    list_value[2] = round(list_value[2] - (j * 2.58))

colorList = np.array(rgbValues)
```

HITGRID

```py
hitGrid = np.full((GRIDX, GRIDY), 100)
```

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/7QCRb3dQ

Comment: Indices start at 0. Yes, 40 is out of bounds for a list with 40 elements. Valid indices are from 0 to 39.

Comment: How would I make it within the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) stores data in row major order. Therefore, you must first specify the number of rows:

<s>`hitList = np.empty((GRIDX, GRIDY))`</s>

```py
hitList = np.empty((GRIDY, GRIDx))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that. Was that in the docs?

Comment: @WebDevStudent Yes, you just have to follow the link in the answer ([numpy.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)): *"[...] the newly created array will be in C order (row major) [...]"*